# Does this matrix series have an answer?

Tags: sequences-and-series, matrices, power-series

I'm trying to solve this series:

$$\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^{k}A^i B C^{k-i}$$

Where A, B, and C are $N\times N$ symmetric matrices. And $A$ and $C$ have spectral radii smaller than or equal to 1, i.e.,

$$\rho(A), \rho(C) \leq 1$$

Does this series have a closed form answer? What if $A=C$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt that you'll get anything more "closed form" than the following:

Consider orthonormal bases $u_m$ of eigenvectors for $A$ with eigenvalues $\lambda_m$ and $v_n$ of eigenvectors for $C$ with eigenvalues $\mu_n$. 
Let $b_{mn} = u_m^T B v_n$. Then assuming all $\lambda_m \ne \mu_n$,
your sum

$$ S_k = \sum_{i=0}^k A^i B C^{k-i} = \sum_{i=0}^k \sum_{m,n=1}^N \lambda_m^i 
\mu_n^{k-i} b_{mn} u_m v_n^T = \sum_{m,n=1}^N \dfrac{\lambda_m^{k+1} - \mu_n^{k+1}}{\lambda_m - \mu_n} b_{mn} u_m v_n^T $$

If $\lambda_m = \mu_n$, the coefficient $\dfrac{\lambda_m^{k+1} - \mu_n^{k+1}}{\lambda_m - \mu_n}$ is replaced by $(k+1) \lambda_m^k$.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $u_mb_{mn}v_n^T$?

Comment: $b_{mn}$ is a scalar, so $u_m b_{mn} v_n^T$ and $b_{mn} u_m v_n^T$ are the same.